# Build a Scala package dependency graph

Tags: scala, graph, dependencies, sbt, typesafe-activator

My scala (Activator + Play) project starts getting huge. I want to split it into multiple small packages. 
However, as a starting point I need to know which file/package depends on which file/package!

How can I obtain a tree or a graph of dependencies among my files?

I tried `sbt-dependendy-graph` but it gives *external* dependencies...

Any clue?

Comment: A project indended to do it but it seems no longer maintained: https://github.com/dwijnand/sbt-project-graph

You could consider migrating it to your Scala version.

Comment: @AlbanDericbourg this plugin is for _inter-project_ dependencies, not for packages/files dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I misread it. Sorry.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want something similar to Haskell's [graphmod](https://github.com/yav/graphmod/wiki) but for Scala?

Comment: @aij yes, quite like that! Dependencies between modules/classes/files within the same project.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I know is [acyclic](https://github.com/lihaoyi/acyclic), which lets you enforce that the package dependency graph is acyclic. There's already [an issue](https://github.com/lihaoyi/acyclic/issues/15) asking for a way of visualizing the dependency graph. Looking at the code, it should be easy to build something like what you want, check [DependencyExtraction.scala](https://github.com/lihaoyi/acyclic/blob/master/src/main/scala/acyclic/plugin/DependencyExtraction.scala) and [GraphAnalysis.scala](https://github.com/lihaoyi/acyclic/blob/master/src/main/scala/acyclic/plugin/GraphAnalysis.scala)